# How can we validate the pdf form using javascript?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

I am planning to validate the entire PDF form using JavaScript. I was just wondering is there any pre-defined functionality for validation? if not please suggest me how can i write the script for validations?

Comment: Please explain this a little more. Are you going to put JavaScript into the PDF and use that for validation? If so, how are you going to do that? Or are you using an external library to validate the PDF?

Comment: yes, I am using itext to put javascript into the pdf and also for pdf population.

Comment: And when does this validation occur? On a button press? On keypress? When a field is "left"? Also, do all of the PDF clients you support have JavaScript enabled for PDF and if not is there a fallback?

Comment: we have a button on the pdf form. when user clicks on the submit button, we are submitting the pdf form to servlet. but the issue is users are clicking double, so form is submitting twice and users are seeing the issue.

Comment: Have you looked through this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13311991/231316